# Changing the "Appendices counter" from \alph to \arabic

Tags: numbering, counters, appendices

I am trying to get the "Chapter number" in the \begin{appendices} to be a number instead of a Letter.

Since I need 2 appendice chapters, one called appendix and one called "Bilag", where Appendix have to be with letters, and bilag have to be with numbers, I have made a new environment that should be able to do it, but I can´t seem to figure out the right command

```
%Bilag
\newenvironment{Bilag}[1]{
%Reset Appendix counter, and making it into numbers
\makeatletter
\setcounter{@ppsaveapp}{0}

\renewcommand{\the@apps}{\arabic{@apps}} %This is the one that is supposed to work?

\makeatother

%Choosing the name of the new environment and adding it
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Bilag}
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Bilag}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Bilag}
\begin{appendices}#1}
{\end{appendices}}
```

Comment: Can you post a compilable MWE, i.e., from \documentclass{...}...\begin{document}...\end{document}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main reason your code is not working is that you are using the wrong counter. The `@pps` counter doesn't count appendix chapters/sections, but `appendices` environments. The counter used to number individual appendix chapters/sections is either `chapter` or `section`, depending on your document class.

Because the `appendices` environment redefines `\thechapter` or `\thesection`, you should moreover redefine these macros *after* `\begin{appendices}`.

I think the following probably does what you want.
If you are using the `article` class you should replace all instances of `chapter` below by `section`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\restoreapp}{} %% <- Start numbering at 1 in every 'appendices'

% \usepackage[danish]{babel} %% <- Uncomment if you are using babel
% \addto\captionsdanish{ %% <- Uncomment if you are using babel
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Appendiks}
  \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendikser}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendikser}
% } %% <- Uncomment if you are using babel

\newenvironment{bilag}{
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Bilag}
  \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Bilag}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Bilag}
  \appendices %% <- would be called as part of \begin{appendices}
  % \setcounter{chapter}{0} %% <- Not needed if you redefine \restoreapp above
  \renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}} %% <- Should come AFTER \appendices
}{
  \endappendices %% <- would be called as part of \end{appendices}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{A section}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{First appendix}
\section{A section}
\chapter{Second appendix}
\section{A section}
\end{appendices}

\begin{bilag}
\chapter{First bilag}
\section{A section}
\chapter{Second bilag}
\section{A section}
\end{bilag}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I don't understand what you want, but here is a guess:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Abstract}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{First Appendix section}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\chapter{Bilag}
\section{First Bilag section}

\backmatter
\chapter{Final thoughts}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table of contents]